# How to force browser to download all static files every time?

Tags: server, cache, browsers

Is it possible to force browser to not using cache and download all files (html/js/css) every time?
I am looking for a server side solution.

Comment: Turning off, or forcing an empty cache is only available on the Client's browser settings.  The only tools I know of server side enable faster caching for serving pages

Comment: A search for 'cachebuster' should help somewhat - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281127/how-do-i-implement-a-cache-buster-if-i-use-git

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @closetnoc I use servers Apache2 and Jetty.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on the web server by sending the correct HTTP headers for those content types. See the [W3C HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) cache control rules. The most important header for your scenario is:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This directive alone should be enough to ensure no proxy or user agent will cache the content.

For Apache, use [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) to send cache directives based on the content type requested.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what I was thinking. That's what I get for insomniac posting.